# Use posts title's for URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a blog and I want when I browse a post to use its title on the URL rather than the default "posts/[:id]", e.g. posts/1 or posts/2.

I did place this code-segment to post.rb file

```
  def to_param
    title
  end
```

which represents the post's title. The issue is that titles may have spaces like "Welcome to the blog" title and this leads to errors when I try to link to the post's page.

I have seen other platforms like Wordpress that automatically replace spaces with dashes. But I don't have a clue how to do this in Rails.

Any idea or guidance to the correct direction will be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073990/pretty-url-in-rails-when-linking?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to call parameterize on the title

```
def to_param
   title.parameterize
end
```

This will make it a friendly URL with the spaces replaced by dashes.  I believe if you don't include the id before title Active Record's `find` won't work.  This would require you to have:

```
def to_param
    "#{id} #{title}".parameterize
end
```

If you are looking for more versatility check out [Friendly ID gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) and this railscast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast

Mainly be careful that your routes and calls still work after you make the changes.